# logging on Azure

Tags: azure, log4net

How can we log on Azure withe the granularity & control equivalent to log4net? We use log4net in our web apps we run on IIS and that works very well for us. Is that the best on Azure too?

We absolutely prefer log files ([as opposed to database entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249797/working-azure-logging-setup)) but if there's something that works better in Azure, I'm open to improvements. The way Trace writes to a table in Azure is horrible - we definitely don't want that.

The reason I prefer log files is it's super easy to see what happened in sequence which is what I need 99% of the time.

This is for an Azure web app that will have multiple instances. It's fine if the logs are distinct to each instance.

thanks - dave

Comment: Is this an Azure Website or a Cloud Service?  For websites, you can simply log to a file.  Browsing the website via Visual Studio will allow you to download the view the log file pretty easily.

Comment: @BrendanGreen yes a website, not a cloud service. Is it that easy - just plain old log4net writing to a file? If so, is there a link showing how to configure the location of the log file?

Comment: @BrendanGreen - ps, write all that as an answer and I'm happy to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward.  I use the following `log4net` configuration to dump a log file in the web application root folder (easily changed to a sub-folder):

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <param name="File" value="my_web.log" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date{yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger.%method [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

I then inspect the log file when needed directly from Visual Studio (double clicking the file downloads it) Server Explorer:

[image: Azure Website via Server Explorer]

Comment: Is that safe - to just put value="my_web.log"? I worry that the default folder is not a safe thing to depend on in a web app.

Comment: It depends I guess on how you configure your website.  Just like `web.config`, I have blocked `*.log` from being served by the site. Alternatively you can also specify a sub-folder for the log files, such as `logs\my_web.log`

Answer (score 11):

I think you should be careful when storing the log file locally in Azure as this is not garanteed to stick around. The VM used to store the website can be reimaged and the logs will be lost.

A better solution is to use Azure diagnostics combined with log4net (would work the same for other logging mechanisms such as NLog). Process is sumarrized here:

1. Set up local storage as a place on the role instance (virtual machine) where log files are written.
2. Add a  element to the diagnostics.wadcfg file to instruct Azure diagnostics to create and use a container in blob storage.
3. Add a  element within  to instruct Azure diagnostics to monitor the logging folder within the LogStorage local resource location.

This way the locally stored logs will be copied to the blob storage.

Full story here: http://justazure.com/microsoft-azure-diagnostics-part-1-introduction/

Comment: Upvoted for the persistence observation, but your solution is for Cloud Services; the OP is running in Azure Websites.

Comment: We have successfully used the same approach, to integrate Azure Websites with Azure diagnosis. Let me know if you still encounter problems and can go into more details.

Comment: @StefanIancu I have a simple ASP NET MVC web app. I set up the storage account, but I do not have a file named `diagnostics.wadcfg`. Also it is weird, in my storage monitoring it says that I have 6500 requests in TABLE, but when I click on tables, it says that "No tables found".

Comment: @Jaanus I assume you have activated the logging from the Azure Portal for your web app. Try to use an app such as [Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) or [Table Explorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/tablexplorer). We are also using [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com) but this has been discontinued. However you can still download the code and make changes to meet your specific needs, this is what we did in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to log data for Azure VMs or Cloud Services is to use Log4Net to log to disk as well as log information from all your instances to an Azure storage account. The advantage is that you will get a more robust solution. If for some reason Azure Diagnostics breaks during a live site, you can still remote into any of the instances and try to diagnose the issue. For other services such as web apps, where you can't remote into the instances, it is sufficient to log information to Azure Storage accounts.

1. **Logging To Disk:** If you have a cloud service, your web role/worker role will only have permission to write to the application disk which is quite small as shown [here](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2015/09/17/not-enough-space-on-the-disk-azure-cloud-services.html) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2012/10/05/windows-azure-disk-partition-preservation/). If you are happy with logging not more than say 200-300 MB of disk space then you are good. However, if you would like to log more then it might be best to use the concept of **LocalStorage** which will allow you to reserve space on the C drive which has a huge amount of space (for Small PaaS VMs Drive C has 225 GB roughly while the application drive (E:/F:) has 1.5 GB of space). You can learn how to use local storage [here](https://convective.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/local-storage-on-windows-azure/).
2. **Logging to Azure Storage Account:** You will need to active Azure Diagnostics as shown [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/microsoft-azure-diagnostics-part-1-introduction/). Furthermore, you will have to add a Trace Appender to Log4Net as shown [here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/10/22/logging-with-log4net-and-azure-diagnostics-on-web-and-worker-roles/).

It will take you half a day or a day to setup and test but I hope that answers your question.