# Using log4net on Azure worker role - writing to a file

Tags: azure, log4net, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

I know the arguments against writing the log to a file on an Azure cloud service (can go away anytime when the system is re-provisioned). However, up till now it has worked 100% of the time, it's simple & straightforward, and reading a file is the easiest way to make use of a log.

But after publishing yesterday, which did include updating log4net to the latest version, while it continued to work for our web role, it now does not work for our worker role. The logs folder is not created and no file is created.

What do we need to change in the below?

```
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <logger name="net.windward">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="WindwardReportsDrivers.net.windward">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <!-- This is E:\logs on the cloud server -->
        <param name="File" value="\logs\LicenseWebServer.log" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date{yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger.%method - %message%newline%exception" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901782/logging-on-azure) answered it with the solution that used to work for both, but now works just for the web roles.

Comment: Working for me... however I wouldn't rely on log files, they do disappear every time the server is shutdown